# How to change SHAPE of UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage

Hey guys how to change the shape of UIImage like this:
This is the original one:

[image]

And this is the way I wanna it be:

[image]

If you get any idea about this, please leave a message. Thx:)

Comment: There is a whole framework in iOS called CoreImage which is built to do just this. You can find many tutorials online. What you are looking for is a `CIFilter` and more specifically a `CIDistortionFilter`. They are a bit fiddly to create and use but it makes doing this sort of thing very very easy. :D

Comment: @Jack Easiest way to do this is use that shaped image with same background color and with transperent shape

Comment: Take a look here for some tutorials about CoreImage... https://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try coreImage. Hope I can figure it out:)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by layer transformation.

```
self.imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(self.imgView.layer.transform, 1, 1, 1.5)
```

Here you need to play with `z position` of layer transformation.

Please refer [CATransform3D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransform3d) for more detail...

Comment: Thanks , but I have to operate the UIImage not imageView this time:)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with transform. But not scale - you need to setup perspective, and rotate you view a bit around x axis:

```
    // Take Identity matrix
    var perspectiveMatrix = CATransform3DIdentity
    // Add perspective.
    perspectiveMatrix.m34 = -1.0 / 1000.0
    // Rotate by 30 degree
    let rotationMatrix = CATransform3DRotate(self.perspectiveMatrix,CGFloat.pi / 6.0, 1, 0, 0)
    //Apply transform
    view.layer.transform = rotationMatrix
```

You can apply transform in `UIView.animation` block to make smooth animation.

Comment: PS: play with angles - I can't remember in what direction it will rotate your view.

Comment: PSS: Don't forget to change bg colour :) if you want it on white

Comment: Actually I wanna white a image clipper for my self, so I guess I have to work with UIImage not the UIImageView this time. But thanks man.

Comment: @Jack then you can use perspective transform and rotation filter using CoreImage http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/a-look-at-perspective-transform.html